# Kafka in raft Mode SASL_SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, mtls

I'm, trying to setup 3 kafka brokers and 3 kafka controllers in full SSL transaction.

Right now,i'm able to do **SASL_PLAINTEXT** for user that trying to create topic as super user (for example) but not with SSL protocol.
The communication inter broker protocol is already set in **SSL**.

But i'm not able to get a proper config to communicate into **SASL_SSL** mechanisms PLAIN (or SCRAM-512). Between client and brokers.

Maybe someone here have an idea about a config in **RAFT** mode to be able to do this?

I've already read that RAFT didn't set up this protocol. But the post was many months ago.

Here my configuration :

````
 

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of

# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.

#   FORMAT:

#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port

#   EXAMPLE:

#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

listeners=EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9143,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9192,SSL://0.0.0.0:9092

 

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.

# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".

#advertised.listeners=SSL://:9092

advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://gateway-external:9143,INTERNAL://proxy-internal:9192,SSL://:9092

 

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details

listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:SSL,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,SSL:SSL,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SSL

 

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

 

listener.name.external.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \

   username="admin" \

   password="admin-secret" \

   user_admin="admin-secret" \

   user_alice="alice-secret" \

   user_bitnami="bitsecret" \

   user_kafkabroker1="kafkabroker1-secret";

#

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network

num.network.threads=3

 

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O

num.io.threads=8

 

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

 

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

 

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

 

############################# Log Basics #############################

 

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files

log.dirs=/opt/bitnami/kafka/data

 

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater

# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across

# the brokers.

num.partitions=1

 

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.

# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

 

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################

# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"

# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

 

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

 

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync

# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.

# There are a few important trade-offs here:

#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.

#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.

#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.

# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or

# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

 

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk

#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

 

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush

#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

 

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

 

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can

# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.

# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens

# from the end of the log.

 

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age

log.retention.hours=168

 

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining

# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.

#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

 

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.

#log.segment.bytes=1073741824

 

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according

# to the retention policies

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

 

############################# Zookeeper #############################

 

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).

# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk

# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".

# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the

# root directory for all kafka znodes.

#zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

 

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper

#zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

 

############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

 

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.

# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.

# The default value for this is 3 seconds.

# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.

# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.

#group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

 

allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false

authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer

auto.create.topics.enable=false

controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER

controller.quorum.voters=0@kafkac-0:9093,1@kafkac-1:9093,2@kafkac-2:9093

inter.broker.listener.name=SSL

 

node.id=3

process.roles=broker

ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^CN=(.*?),OU=(.*?),O=(.*?),L=(.*?),ST=(.*?),C=(.*?)$/$1/L,DEFAULT

super.users=User:kafkac-0;User:kafkac-1;User:kafkac-2;User:kafkab-0;User:kafkab-1;User:kafkab-2;User:kafka-cli;User:schema-registry;User:kafka-rest

ssl.client.auth=required

ssl.keystore.type=JKS

ssl.truststore.type=JKS

ssl.key.password=kafka-amd

ssl.keystore.location=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks

ssl.truststore.location=/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks

ssl.keystore.password=kafka-amd

ssl.truststore.password=kafka-amd

# listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required user_user="bitnami";

# listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required;

# listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-512.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required;

############################# Metrics Settings #############################

metric.reporters=org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter

#com.sun.management.jmxremote=true

#com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

#com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

#java.rmi.server.hostname=kafkab-0

#java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

#com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

## com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5556

#com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5556```
````